# Dockerize an Angular Library

Tags: angular, docker

Can I use docker images to release an angular library and publish it for my other members of team so they don’t have access to the source code but can use like `dll` files in windows?

If not, how can I publish my libraries? I do not want to use `npm` cause in development process it would cost time and resource alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend it to publish to repository manager i.e nexus and share .if not then private git repo will also work fine .